# Returning first letters of words in a string

Tags: python, string

This was the question asked in my class:
Write and test a function that takes a name as a parameter and returns the initials of the name. For example, "Augusta Ada King" should return "A.A.K."; "Frank Lloyd Wright" should return "F.L.W."; "Alan Turing" should return "A.T.". Your solution should handle names of any length.

### My code so far is written as follows:

---

```
def make_intitals(name):

    char_length = len(name)
    initial = name[0:1]
    for i in range(char_length):
        if name[i] == '':
            initial_location = name[i+1]
            initial += '.' + initial_location
    return initial.upper()


given_name = input("Enter name: ")

initials = make_intitals(given_name)

print(initials)
```

---

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `name[i] == ''` will never be true. I think you mean `name[i] == ' '`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getInitials(full_name):

    s = full_name.split(" ");
    initials = [];

    for i in range(0, len(s)-1):
        initials.append(s[i][0])

    return initials

full_name = raw_input("Please enter the name "); # Only works for Python version 3> 
#full_name = input("Please enter a name"); # Works only for older versions like 2.7

res = getInitials(full_name); # Should work fine "Returns P. A. for Peter Aaron Jackson"
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: I ended up adding a space in the name[i] == ' ' and it worked. Thank you for the response though!

Comment: @NicholasCullen       Good to hear :) Update post if you have a follow-up question :)

Answer (score 0):

well perhaps an easier approach you have to pick always the first char and then iterate if a whitespace occurs take the following index:

```
s = "jon doe test"
l = list(s)
n = ""
n+= s[0]
for e, i in enumerate(l):
    if i == ' ':
    n+= l[e+1]
print n
```

you can use enumerate if yout want to work with the implicit index like in a C-style for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
initials = ''
for name in full_name.split(' '):
  initials += name[0] + '.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I wrote for you,

```
def initial(n):
  n=n.split(" ")
  i=0
  while i<len(n):
    print n[i][0]
    i=i+1
  return
```

when you run the function like:
    `initial("John Doe Smith")`

the answer will show up in output as:
J
D
S

Comment: Why in the world would you write this using a `while` loop? It's so much simpler (and more "Pythonic") to use a `for` loop on the list you got from `split`. In fact, you can do the whole function in one line, using a generator expression like so: `def initials(n): print("\n".join(w[0] for w in n.split(" ")))`

Comment: Thanks @Blckknght of course, that's the best way to write it. I just made it simple to be able to be presented in his class. But I agree the one line solution is the more "Pythonic" and professional one :)